# Hardcoded ClaimIdentity doesn't create a cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identity

I've tested viewing the cookies created with Firebug and with the browser tool, but when I'm logged, I haven't cookies created.
I've defined the cookie authentication in ~/Startup.cs (I'm using Identity framework), and I've checked I was indentified with "Hello, @User.Identity.Name".

My sources:
I've created a login ActionResult (~/Controller/AccountController.cs) and a login model (~/Model/LoginModel.cs), and when I login (~/View/Account/Login.cshtml) with "admin@admin.com, "password", then the controller **should** create a cookie.

~/Controller/AccountController.cs

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Security.Claims;
//using MyProject.Models;

namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        // GET: account
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            var model = new LoginModel
            {
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl
            };

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }

            // Don't do this in production!
            if (model.Email == "admin@admin.com" && model.Password == "password")
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Ben"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "a@b.com"),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Country, "England")
                },
                    "ApplicationCookie");

                var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
                var authManager = ctx.Authentication;

                // CREATE THE COOKIE
                authManager.SignIn(identity);

                // Finally we redirect the user agent to the resource they attempted to access. We also check to ensure the return URL is local to the application to prevent Open Redirection attacks
                return Redirect(GetRedirectUrl(model.ReturnUrl));
            }

            // user authN failed
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid email or password");
            return View();
        }

        private string GetRedirectUrl(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) || !Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Url.Action("Index", "Home");
            }

            return returnUrl;
        }
    }
}
```

~/Model/LoginModel

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

~/Startup.cs

```
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;

//[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyProject.Startup))]
namespace MyProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// To initialize the OWIN identity components we need to add a Startup class to the project
    /// </summary>
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // This is a string value that identifies the the cookie. This is necessary since we may have several instances of the Cookie middleware. For example, when using external auth servers (OAuth/OpenID) the same cookie middleware is used to pass claims from the external provider
                AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",

                // The path to which the user agent (browser) should be redirected to when your application returns an unauthorized (401) response. This should correspond to your "login" controller
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });
        }
    }
}
```

~/View/Login.cshtml

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <p>
        <button type="submit">Log In</button>
    </p>
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried what you're doing myself. But I would start verifying that `Startup.Configuration` runs.

Comment: It runs. You have my Startup class in this thread.

Comment: This may or may not be related. http://coding.abel.nu/2014/11/catching-the-system-webowin-cookie-monster/ You're using the middleware in an unconventional way that may lead to all kinds of unexpected behavior. Good luck. If you get it working I hope you'll share the answer with us.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622047/identity-cookie-loses-custom-claim-information-after-a-period-of-time) answer. You may need to add your claims in ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync method.

Comment: Hello! This link only provide security for the cookies. The problem is I'm logged but "magically" there isn't cookies in the browser.