# Why after adding a claim in login action, it can’t be accessed in other controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2, claims

I'm working on a system that uses ASP.NET MVC 5 and Identity 2 with Entity Framework 6. 
When a user logs in, I add some claims to that login session. I don’t want to use the claims table.

For one of my claims, I did like this:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User, int> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        //We add the display name so that the _LoginPartial can pick it up;
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("DisplayName", FirstName + " " + LastName));

        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
    public virtual ICollection<UserInsurance> UserInsurances { get; set; }
    public User()
    {
        UserInsurances = new List<UserInsurance>();
    }
}
```

And for accessing the claim:

```
var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
var displayNameClaim = claimsIdentity != null
    ? claimsIdentity.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == "DisplayName")
    : null;
var nameToDisplay = displayNameClaim == null ? User.Identity.Name : displayNameClaim.Value;
```

This works well. But the problem is when I need a field that is not in the User table. In fact, it is one record in the user’s navigation property (UserInsurances) and I need a linq query for access that.

```
var lastUserInsurance = UserInsurances.OrderByDescending(x => x.CompanyInsuranceId).First();
userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("CompanyInsuranceId", lastUserInsurance.CompanyInsuranceId.ToString()));
```

If I put this code in GenerateUserIdentityAsync method like “DisplayName”, UserInsurances is null. So I should add this code to login action and after the user logs in successfully. But I tried that and it doesn’t work. I don’t know why but when I want to access that claim, it does not exist.

```
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                var user = _user.Include(x => x.UserInsurances).FirstOrDefault(x => x.NationalCode == model.UserName);
                var identity = await SignInManager.CreateUserIdentityAsync(user);
                var lastUserInsurance = user.UserInsurances.OrderByDescending(x => x.CompanyInsuranceId).FirstOrDefault();
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("CompanyInsuranceId", lastUserInsurance.CompanyInsuranceId.ToString()));
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why I can’t access this claim and it does not exist? I don’t know how I implement this scenario and access “CompanyInsuranceId” claim in all parts of my application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must add your claims before sign the user in. So if for any reason you can not fill your claims in `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` method. Simply generate `Identity` object in the log in action method then sign in it. Consider this example:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model,string returnUrl)
{
    var user = UserManager.Find(model.Email, model.Password);
    // now you have the user object do what you to gather claims

    if(user!=null)
    {
        var ident = UserManager.CreateIdentity(user, 
            DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            ident.AddClaims(new[] {
                new Claim("MyClaimName","MyClaimValue"),
                new Claim("YetAnotherClaim","YetAnotherValue"),
        });
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(
            new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, 
            ident);
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
    return View(model);
}
```

As you can see you could do anything you want to gather claims and fill the identity then sign in the user.

But if you want use `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()` method simply override `SignInManager.CreateUserIdentityAsync()` method in a way so you could generate desired claims. For example if you need `DbContext` to fetch extra information for feeding your claims simply you could inject `DbContext` in `SignInManager` and use it in `CreateUserIdentityAsync()` method like this:

```
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public ApplicationSignInManager(
        ApplicationUserManager userManager, 
        IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
        ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
        _context=context;
    }

    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var companyInsuranceId=_context.Users
            .Where(u=>u.NationalCode == user.UserName)
            .Select(u=>u.UserInsurances
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.CompanyInsuranceId)
                .Select(x=>x.CompanyInsuranceId)
                .FirstOrDefault())
            .FirstOrDefault();

        var ident=user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
        ident.AddClaim(new Claim("CompanyInsuranceId",
            companyInsuranceId.ToString()));
        return ident;
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(
            context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(),
            context.Authentication,
            context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>());
    }
}
```

Now simply just by writing

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
    model.UserName, model.Password, 
    model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

you could sign the user in and inject additional claims.

Comment: Thanks. It works well. But as you said I want to use SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync() method, but I can't use SignInManager.CreateUserIdentityAsync() because I don't access the user's navigation property (User.UserInsurances) in this method and it is null. So what is your suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: I think "User.UserInsurances" is null because I disable lazy loading.

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. I think it’s the best solution for my issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For MVC5, additional claims can be added easily via the ApplicationUser class.

eg.

```
    public ClaimsIdentity GenerateUserIdentity(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here

        return userIdentity;
    }
```

This also resolve
[Identity cookie loses custom claim information after a period of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622047/identity-cookie-loses-custom-claim-information-after-a-period-of-time)

Comment: Thanks, but as I said I needed DbContext to fetch extra information for feeding my claims that is not in User class.